# Install Chromium on Ubuntu MATE (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: ubuntu, chromium

I've installed chromium using

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

and am unable to open chromium. If I try to open it from the terminal I get this error

```
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
 kenneth@kenneth-pi:~$ [14940:14940:0402/144609:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(334)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
```

any idea how to fix this issue?

Edit:
I've also installed the Ubuntu Software Center and installed it from there, but still on luck.

Comment: Can you send output of `chromium --version` and `uname -r` (add to your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following commands from the terminal in any Raspberry Pi 2 or 3 operating system that is Debian based should allow you to install Chromium with no issues. I can confirm that it works on Ubuntu MATE 15.10 and Raspbian Jessie.

```
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-browser-l10n_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_all.deb
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-browser_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb

sudo dpkg -i chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser-l10n_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_all.deb chromium-browser_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
```

Comment: vote down because the links are dead, if you fix it i change my vote ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same segmentation problem on Ubuntu Mate and after many tries, including downloading from unofficial sources (dangerous) and compiling it myself and I gave up but yesterday I managed to get it to work. I suspect that a new, less buggy version of Chromium has been released (version 55), but here is exactly what I have done.

Do a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate, and immediately reboot. NOTE: If you have the Rpi 3 and use wifi there is a known bug, you must restart the Pi after a fresh install in order to make the wifi available.

Go to System > Administration > Software & Updates. Under “downloadable from the Internet” tick everything. Then under “other software” tick everything (you can leave out source code if you want). Then under “updates” I unticked everything and turned else off because we can update the Pi ourselves with apt-get.

Then in a terminal

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

Go to the Welcome Screen > Getting Started > Firmware Update

```
    sudo apt-get install raspi-config
    sudo raspi-config
```

In raspi-config go to "Increase file system" and then reboot.

```
    sudo apt-get update 
    sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Reboot one last time.

```
   sudo apt-get update
```

I had an error with auto-updates, it complained about a file (20-auto-updates) or something. I used the file manager (Caja) to move the file it complained about to my home directory with

```
    gksu caja /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
```

Go to Software Boutique > Install Chromium.

This loaded & worked fine but video sites like YouTube, BBC iPlayer etc weren't so good, they were almost unwatchable. I am uncertain if buying the codecs from Rpi will fix it as YouTube / iPlayer works fine on OSMC. I am going to try installing the Ubuntu Codecs & non free chromium codecs to see if that makes it better and report back.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry Pi doesn't setup virtual memory space by default. So when chromium loads, the system runs out of memory and Chormium crashes.

You can simply install dphys-swapfile `sudo apt install dphys-swapfile` to add a virtual memory subsystem. This which will prevent chromium from immediately crashing due to lack of memory space. It should also greatly increase the systems stability.

I know this is an old thread but I hope this helps. (Since this was the first thing that popped up for me when I was looking for a solution.)

Eric

Answer (score -1):

This is for the 64 bit version.

Download using :

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Install .dem file :

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Fix errors :

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Use Google Chrome with :

```
google-chrome
google-chrome http://www.cyberciti.biz/
```

Comment: this does not work. I get this error.
    dpkg: error processing archive google-chrome-    stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (armhf)
Errors were encountered while processing:

Comment: As Kenneth points out, this is simply **wrong**.  There is no possibility at all of the x86-64 version working on the Pi 3.

Comment: @goldilocks Yeah, exactly. You'd need ExaGear for that, and there's no point to even trying to run x86 programs when there's a version for armhf