# Chromium issue on Rpi3 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, chromium, rdp

I can't get Chromium to work on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 for Rpi 3.

I installed the one from the package manager.
I already tried to do the answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45150/install-chromium-on-ubuntu-mate-raspberry-pi) but I still have the same error.

I'm not using display, only Xrdp with sesman-xvnc.

When I try to launch I get this.

```
romain@romain-pi:~$ chromium-browser
Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":10.0".
Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":10.0".
Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":10.0".
Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":10.0".
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[2872:2872:0906/234600:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(386)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[2872:2872:0906/234600:ERROR:gl_surface_x11.cc(252)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
romain@romain-pi:~$
```